# Can we use Bluetooth to transfer money from one person to another?

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to transfer money from one person to another using Bluetooth technology without using the Internet?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As you can copy every digital data (thus also digital coins) you always need to have a central instance to register money transactions. Usually these instances are a central server (e.g. of a bank) or a distributed system like Bitcoin.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that there are existing apps to do this.  But if you are going to write an app, then you can do what you want, within reason.  Whether it will be usable, secure, fast enough is up to you to determine and solve.

Comment: Thank you.. Is there any guide line or documentation to follow